# deploying a precompiled website: Ambiguous match found error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-applications, web-deployment, precompiled, vs-web-site-project

I'm trying to deploy a website (website project) made in Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4. I've selected publish in VS, and left precompiled website selected. Then I copied the result on the ftp, and got this error:

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Ambiguous match found.

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ control inherits="ASPNetPortal.Welcome, App_Web_bsx3gdjs" language="c#" %>
Line 2:  <%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="Footer" Src="Footer.ascx" %>
Line 3:  <style type="text/css">    

Source File: /DesktopModules/Welcome.ascx    Line: 1
```

The site works fine on localhost (in VS). What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have two fields that differ only in casing (1).

(1) - http://www.onpreinit.com/2009/09/ambiguous-match-found_30.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late for answering, but I just had this same problem.  If you only have a *website*, you don't need to compile the dlls - just use the raw code files.  If you want dlls, you have to use a *web application* instead of a *web site*.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735054/how-to-convert-asp-net-website-to-asp-net-web-application) about how to convert your *website* to a *web application*.  Once you do that, you'll get all those compile errors right in VS, and can resolve them.

The particular error you see is because as a web application, the code is more particular about what you name the partial classes in the code behind files.  Every one has to be named differently in order to resolve that particular error.