# Can't include Microsoft.Security.Application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, namespaces, antixsslibrary

I can't include **Microsoft.Security.Application**

```
using Microsoft.Security.Application;
```

Gives this error:

> The type or namespace name 'Security' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

And yes, I clicked on **Bin -> Add Reference... -> AntiXSSLibrary.dll** and it added it to the Bin Folder including the AntiXSSLibrary.xml.

I rebuilt the whole website, and still nothing.

I'm using ASP .NET 3.5 C# - [AntiXSSLibrary 4.0 Stable](http://wpl.codeplex.com/)

Comment: is AntiXSSLibrary.dll the correct library? It doesn't seem to agree with you.

Comment: Are there any warnings/messages? Look at your output window.

Comment: No Warnings/Messages.
And what you mean is the correct library. 
Offcourse it is.

Comment: Is there a naming conflict? A class called Mirosoft? Try adding the namespace using global ( using global::Microsoft.Security.Application; )

Comment: @Polity Yes it's conflicting with the Microsoft namespace..
`global::Microsoft.Security.Application;` Wont work either.

Comment: @polity Nope :(
it didn't fix it

Comment: Right, i dont think namespaces can conflict with one another, only classes can conflict and namespaces with classes. E.g. if you had a class named Microsoft, then he would look op the Property Security on the class rather then the namespace Security in the namespace Microsoft. When using Object Explorer (Ctrl + Alt + J), can you find the namespace your trying to access?

Comment: @polity Nope cant see it there.

Comment: Remove the reference, remove the DLL, Clean project, Rebuild project, Add reference again and try again. If that doesnt work, use a text editor and open [yourproject].vsproj and see if its referenced right. If that doesnt work, try and restart VS ;), else try and compile on another PC. It seems to me that Visual Studio is messing with you

Comment: It's not project, it's a website So i cant Edit/Clean project?
tried Rebuilding removing deleteing readding..
and nothing..

Comment: Right mouse button on your website ->  Convert to webapplication (for me this solved alot of problems coming with Website projects in the past) although i dont really understand why. Else, create a new website and try and reproduce the problem. If you cant, try and find the differences

Comment: Thanks !!!
That worked !
I followed this tutorial: [how-to-convert-asp-net-website-to-asp-net-web-application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735054/how-to-convert-asp-net-website-to-asp-net-web-application)
Type you full answer so i can mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right mouse on your website -> Convert to webapplication. See: [How To Convert ASP.NET Website to ASP.NET Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735054/how-to-convert-asp-net-website-to-asp-net-web-application?lq=1)

Answer (score 30):

If you get this nuget all extention objects are visibles

Install-Package AntiXSS

it solves my problem.

`html = Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(model.SiteName),
model = Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(json),`

Answer (score 5):

Uninstall and re-install AntiXSS:

Tools --> NuGet Package Manager --> Package Manager Console (UI may differ if using other than Visual Studio 2013):

```
Uninstall-Package AntiXSS
Install-Package AntiXSS
```

For multi-project solutions, be sure to set the default project to whichever one is experiencing the problem. Use `Uninstall-Package -Force AntiXSS` if uninstall fails and if you can handle any package dependency problems that may arise, though I know of none for this package.

Answer (score 2):

If, like me, you're using `AntiXSSLibrary` in a class library via `Nuget`, and got the above error:

1. Remove all external references that you had through Nuget
2. Remove the Nuget package file - which is `packages.config` found in the solution's root directory
3. Remove the `packages` directory - again in your solution's root directory
4. Reinstall all your components again

Answer (score 1):

The answer [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1391543.aspx/1) helped me. I found the AntiXssLibrary.dll on my site's bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

Install-Package AntiXSS from Tools --> NuGet Package Manager

Answer (score 0):

You are using 
using Microsoft.Security.Application;

Try this
using System.Web.Security.Application;

For me, it was the other way round. I think it is due to different versions of my AntiXSSScripting dll I'm using.