# How to create project for existing site?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a web app that didn't come with a project file.  Is there a way to create a blank project file, include all existing files into it, without modifying the existing web.config?

Comment: Do you want something like this **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735054/how-to-convert-asp-net-website-to-asp-net-web-application** ??

Comment: Why don't you want to change existing Web.Config? There may be many reasons to do so?

Comment: That risk disabling the existing site.  I just need to put the site into a solution so I can better work with it.

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to make an empty solution and then hit add existing files or folders and just select everything you have?

Comment: @Andrew: Yes.  I was hoping there might be a completely empty solution so I didn't have to overwrite the template web.config and have other unrelated files running around.