# Converting Web Site to a Web App Issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications, web

We have a very large, **VB.NET** solution in `Visual Studio 2010` which contains an ASP.NET Web Site.  The Web was originally created as a Web Site and I need to convert it to a Web App. I have attempted to convert it in Visual Studio 2010 using these sites as guidelines:

[How To Convert ASP.NET Website to ASP.NET Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735054/how-to-convert-asp-net-website-to-asp-net-web-application)

and at Microsoft:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.ASPX

Along with the Web Site, the solution consists of three class library projects that handle things such as the business logic, database calls and models, which defines the data structures as data collections when the data is returned from the database.

The solution also includes the Microsoft Enterprise Library 3.1 and the Web Deploy project, which allows me to compile the web site into its own assembly. There are also nearly a dozen classes in the App_Code folder. Well, the main one is a module, not a class.

Once I converted the web site to an app, I was able to get the solution to compile with no compilation errors. Of course, by default, the App_code folder was changed to Old_App_Code. **However, when I run the app, it does not load properly.**

There are a number of calls throughout the site to methods in the module from APSX pages. At this time, this is where the application is failing. I see this error in the Event Log:

```
Error BC30451: 'TrimTrailingZeros' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

TrimTrailingZeros is a public method in the public module. If I convert the module to a class, I get hundreds of errors (more errors than the Error List can handle).

Right now, I am getting this error that’s preventing my pages to load. I have tried a number of things to get this to work.

*Any suggestions on what should I do so I can get passed this?*

*Let me know if you have further questions.*

Thanks
-Paul

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following link. It will answer your query.

http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.in/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment Jalpesh. I no longer have an App_code folder in the newly converted Web Application. The Build Action for the classes that were converted are set to Compile. 

Interestingly enough, I originally tried to convert this site with VS 2010. Now I am attempting it again in 2013. Adding a new ASP.NET Folder in 2010 does not give you the App_code folder option as described in the blog. But it does give you the option in 2013.

Comment: OK let me know if you still have any problem!!