# How to convert Asp.net website into Asp.net Web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am currently working on Asp.net(3.5) website but the website is growing.I want to convert the website into Asp.net application.I am a bit late in taking this decision but any ways.

While trying to do the same by following this [great article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/10/29/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project.aspx) and the responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735054/how-to-convert-asp-net-website-to-asp-net-web-application) I got many exception which made my life hell.Once thought of creating web Application from scratch but it will take huge time and will be a rework.This made me to ask few question to myself which I bing but didn't get satisfactory answers.

Here they come:

1. What are the key things I should take care before doing the same?
2. How should i start ?
3. I need to rethink about the website architecture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a New Web Application in VS 2013.

1. Using Windows Explorer copy all your files into you project folder.
2. In VS 2013 solution explorer show all files.
3. Select the files and folders - right click include in project.
4. Right click the project solution explorer and select Convert to Web Application.

There are quite a few small differences, such as the App_Code folder will get renamed to old_app_code - that surprisingly doesn't cause any errors. The TypeName on your object data sources and the inherits on the @Page tag might need the [ProjectName]. prefix appended globally.

Comment: **Definitely** make sure that your "app_code" folder gets renamed to something else. I did this in VS2019 (didn't look for the "convert" option mentioned; it's not there now, at least). Everything "app_code" gets auto-compiled separately from the project, which results in all sorts of weird "type conflicts", as well as some confusing Intellisense errors.