# Tips to transform an old vb.net webform appplication into a vb.net solution

Tags: vb.net, webforms, asp.net-4.0

I have an webform vb.net application which has been coded without any solution or project. To deliver this code, I just put it in my IIS website and go for it. There is no need to generate the dll, publish the website or anything.

I don't like this type of coding, and I would like to create a .net solution. I wanted to stay closer as possible from the existing code.

I have some questions about this process (if you can answer juste one or a few of it, you'll help me a lot) :

- Is it doable easily ? Is there an automatic way to do this ? (yes I'm dreaming)
- Have you some tips about the way of doing this ?
- Should i use an empty solution or a webform solution ?
- Should I expect specific problem during this process ?
- [Newbie question alert] I can't find any information about the .net version used in this application... I've found the "CLR .Net version" in IIS config (it's the 4.0) : does it mean that the application use the 4.0 .net framework ?
- My application is separated into 3 sub-applications (front/back/child-application) : can I keep this organisation ? I was thinking about making one solution with 3 projects.

I have not tried anythink yet. I'm at the very beginning of this project.

I have searched on stackoverflow for similar topic but I only found topics about converting vb.net into c#

Thanks a lot for any help you can provide !

Comment: What you have is a web site project and what you want is a web site application: [ASP.NET Web Site or ASP.NET Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/398049/1115360), and [How to convert ASP.NET website to ASP.NET web application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/735054/1115360) would be somewhere to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own questions in case this could help someone :

About version .Net Framework :

It's better to create a blank new project in the same .Net version, and upgrade it at the end (when the project is fully converted)

About the web.config :

Delete the web.config on the new blank project and replace it by the existing one. Try to execute the application and make adjustments

Answer (score 0):

I made the conversion, i still have some namespace error that I'm going to fix. But I have two questions :

1. I made a web application with 4.5 .Net framework although my website was build with 4.0 .Net Framework :

   - do you think I made a mistake ?
   - Should I have updated my website to 4.5 before trying to convert it ?
2. What I am supposed to do with my web.config ?

   - Copy-paste to new solution and erase the web.config that has been created in my web application ?
   - Or should I merge both ?
   - Or keep the new one only ?