# Cant convert website to web application in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to convert an old Visual Basic web site project, into a web application, using VS2019.
I have tried following this:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa983476(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

However, when I copy the remaining files (after converting app_code) and try to convert it to a web application, it is unable to parse any of the aspx files. I haven't been able to find the reason for this. Do any one have any ideas?

Comment: Here is a discussion about website conversion maybe you can refer to. [How to convert ASP.NET website to ASP.NET web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735054/how-to-convert-asp-net-website-to-asp-net-web-application)

Answer (score 13):

I finally found the secret sauce!
You have to select the root project node in Solution Explorer and then select "Project" from the filebar menu (not the right click menu). The very last menu item is "Convert to Web Application"!

Comment: I don't find the command, can you help me with screen?

Comment: Just want to add they mean select the `Project` dropdown from the filebar menu while you have the root project node selected in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: Is this in VS2019? What version of VS does this menu item exist?