Multiple WebForms Contexts causing compiler errors after adding csproj
I have an existing .NET 4.8 Web Forms site that utilizes an app_code/ folder for storing some source files.
To provide improved intellisense in the C# source files, I added a missing .sln and .csproj file to wrap the website (the .csproj uses the Microsoft.NET.Sdk)
After doing this, my code works and the intellisense is functioning, but I'm hitting some odd compiler errors in Visual Studio. In the code-behind of my page, my runat="server" based controls, are showing an error saying the control is not found in the current context.
My theory is the dynamic ASP.NET compilation is getting tripped up over itself due to being wrapped in a project but I'm not quite sure how to tell ASP.NET they are really one in the same and to not treat the new project differently.


Well, how this works will depend on the type of project. To open a asp.net web site, you don't have a .sln project file, but ARE to use file->open web site, and then browse to the folder. However, if you using a asp.net web site "application", then yes, you have a .sln project file. But, the whopper bad news is you can't just out of the blue try to use a "web site" as a web site "application". You in fact have to migrate the project for this to work correctly. This also means that now VS will do the biuld, and not IIS when you copy the files to the web site.

In fact, with a web site, you don't have (nor enjoy) .designer files, and at publish time, no source code (the .vb, or .cs files) are NOT deployed to the web server. So, the 2 types of projects are VAST different in how they operate, and you find even the top most @page directive is slightly different between the two types of projects. You can (and should) thus use the convert to web site feature, but even then, some of the pages and most certainly how the references are managed changes quite a bit here. I don't like web sites, since .dll references resolve to the bin folder which is horrible

So, if this was a "web site", then you need to convert this to a "application" which of course is a far better choice from a developer point of view. This gives the process: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735054/how-to-convert-asp-net-website-to-asp-net-web-application

As usual, if you only have some files such .cs or.aspx files and want to build the project, you need to create a new asp.net webform app and add these existing files to the project. And could you tell me why you want to add  .csproj file Microsoft.NET.Sdk instead of common .csproj file ?
