ASP.NET / VB.NET: compile errors when migrating to .NET 4.8
I have tried to migrate my ASP.NET solution written in VB.NET from .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.8 and organize my solution by creating projects.
The new project has been created using Visual Studio 2019 -> New Project -> ASP.NET Web Application (Webforms). The code that used to compile now displays error messages all throughout the ASPX.VB pages when objects from the underlying forms are referenced (ex : Me.button1.Text ="hello").
I get 20k compile errors, might make it to the world championships...
Admin.aspx:
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="MasterPage.master" CodeBehind="Admin.aspx.vb" Inherits="Main.Admin" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderMain">

    <asp:Button ID="Button_NewProject" runat="server" CssClass="medium_button" Text="NEW PROJECT" Width="250px" />
..............

Admin.aspx.vb:
Public Class Admin
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Me.Button_NewProject.Visible = False  ' <-- "Button_NewProject" is not a member of Admin
...........

I have noticed that when I create a new web form, it creates a DESIGNER.VB file which is missing for the historic ASPX files. Could this be related? Do you see any other cause?
Here is the compiler section in the web.config:
<system.codedom>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
</compilers>

Compile errors are of type:

Error BC30506: Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.

Thanks in advance, I've already spent hours trying to debug that stuff :-/
Actions taken :

Tried to create a new form from an existing one, to match the WebForm1.aspx that works when created in the new environment. It does NOT compile (reference to the only button Me.Button1 fails) despite the fact that the 2 are identical - except for the presence of the Designer.vb file.

Tried to change the Build Action, currently set to CONTENT for ASPX files and COMPILE for ASPX.VB files



Can  you open the older project first, and does it build using vs2019? No use trying to mess around unless the original project builds in the first place. And if that project builds, then simply go project->properties, and on Application tab, try changing the .net framework from 4 to 4.8. If the project builds, then you just upgraded to 4.8. So, no need to create a whole new project, but try opening the existing project. It if builds, then simply try changing the .net framework, and if that builds, then you are done.

The older project compiles but I have a lot of keywords in the web.config file that I suspect are legacy, and this old Solution does not include a Project. I wanted to get a clean 4.8 slate to start anew, and I just can't understand why we can't copy ASPX files, re-create references and start over. Oh well... some say Microsoft focusses on Razor Pages, it's possible they're trying to get people to switch by turning off a couple of features, or just don't care anymore. I'm also getting bugs on VS2022 that I don't have on VS2019, like the shortcut F12 (GoTo Definition)  that doesn't work anymore

You can't just copy the aspx pages, since you trying to change the project type, and you NOT JUST trying to migrate to 4.8, but ALSO doing a project type migration. Hence current aspx pages will have CodeFile= for a web site, and for a asp.net webforms "application" (one with a project file), then all aspx pages will require you to change CodeFile to CodeBehind for each @page directive.  So, to migrate to 4.8 (or 4.8.1), then in that project that builds, you can right click on the Website, and choose property pages, and then on Build,you can choose/change framework to 4.8.1 and you done.

So, migration to 4.8.1, and that of migration of the project type are 2 different goals here. If the web site now builds and runs when you change to 4.8.1, then your migration to 4.8.1 is complete and done. And in most cases, that takes no time at all. Now, 2nd goal is to migrate the project type, and that is a rather different process and different goal. And how references etc. work is different, and thus you need additional steps.  See this for how this works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735054/how-to-convert-asp-net-website-to-asp-net-web-application
